# Silverlight 4 using visual studio 2010 with devexpress 2011 (focus)

Tags: silverlight, focus

I have a problem with silverlight child window.

here is the problem.

I have a silverlight apps inside an aspx.
I have a main page that looks like a form.

In that form there is a textbox / textedit that will be show a silverlight child windows.
This child is used for selecting a value to fill the earlier textbox.

In this silverlight child window there are predefined option loaded from database.
If there is no option match with user criteria, user can add the new option by pressing insert button.

the insert button now will open the second silverlight child window. the problem is appear after I close the second silverlight child window.

after the second child is closed, the focus is focusing on address bar in the browser...

Can anyone help me?

Thanks before

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the silverlight child control, but actually because I using messagebox.show() before close the child.

I don't know how to fix the problem with the messagebox.show(). Therefore I manage to create my own messagebox.